# Stop annoying session keep alive message in ssh login

Tags: macos, ssh

I was trying to change some settings in my MAC for keeping my connection alive for long time. Before it was logging out automatically after some idle time with message "Write Failed: Broken pipe". Now after I changed the setting I am getting annoying message every time to the logged in terminal using ssh

```
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
```

How can I remove this message to appear on my terminal (MAC), or else I can go back to my previous setting?

Comment: You may put a command-line keepalive option with your SSH command as follows:  ssh -o "ServerAliveInterval 5" ..

Comment: Odd, that looks like a debug message you shouldn't be seeing without running ssh with `-v`.

Comment: Sorry but even after passing command " gwsh -2 -v -o "ServerAliveInterval 5" root@192.168.2.104 " , I can see the message on my terminal. My concern is, I just don't want these debug message to appear on my terminal but even if I am idle for 10 seconds, I am getting these message.

Comment: Yes. I think I shouldn't be running ssh -v option, to stop debug message but verbose is required for me, If am tracking the connection process.

Answer (score 13):

You are receiving these messages because you have set `ClientAliveInterval` on the server. The server sends keep-alive packets to the client when the connection stays idle for the specified interval. To prevent these messages:

- On the server, increase `ClientAliveInterval` to a sufficiently high number (e.g. 480 seconds) to prevent connection timeout without flooding your logs.
- On the client, set `ServerAliveInterval` to a number lower than the server's `ClientAliveInterval`. This will cause the client to keep the connection alive without ever triggering the server's keep-alive timeout.

Comment: A better explanation of how we can do any of these would be welcome.

Comment: You'll have to modify the configuration in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. See `man ssh_config` and `man sshd_config` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in one of two places:

1) On the mac in ~/.ssh/config
    - There could be debug flags set in there

2) On the server, as there could be debit flags set there too

Answer (score 2):

*(Easy summary of other answers/comments)*:

Run in terminal of Mac, replacing `5` with number of seconds less than interval between new messages appearing on screen:

`echo "  ServerAliveInterval 5" >> ~/.ssh/config`

You may check if `ServerAliveInterval` line is already there before that:

`cat ~/.ssh/config | grep ServerAliveInterval`

(if you see a line, then edit instead).

Will take effect on next run of `ssh`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting these messages because the server has [`ClientAliveInterval`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ClientAliveInterval) which is not set to 0 (the default).

> Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the client, sshd(8) will send a message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the client. The default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to the client.

## Solutions

### Server: set [`ClientAliveInterval`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ClientAliveInterval) to 0

The simplest solution is to remove the `ClientAliveInterval` on the server, it defaults to 0 and no messages are sent.

Alternatively, set the value to 0.

#### Where?

You typically do this by editing the servers [`sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) which is likely in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. The changes take affect the next time the daemon is started.

#### Notes

For hosted service, [it may be a bad idea to set ClientAliveInterval to 0](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/ssh-keep-alive#3-why-not-set-to-never-disconnect). Mainly because it can keep the host running unnecessarily and waste money.

### Client: set [`ServerAliveInterval`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#ServerAliveInterval) to a lower value than the servers `ClientAliveInterval`

If you don't have access to the server, or you want to configure clients differently. You may set the `ServerAliveInterval` to a value that is lower than the `ClientAliveInterval`. Then the `ssh` client will periodically send messages which reset the server timeout.

#### Where?

You typically do this by the editing the clients [`ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) which is likely in `~/.ssh/config`.

#### Notes

Setting the `ServerAliveInterval` lower than the `ClientAliveInterval` is, for most intents and purposes, the same as not having one. You won't get messages in your terminal.

Nevertheless, it allows for interesting configuration. You can open different `ssh` connections, some which `timeout` and some which don't when used in conjunction with [`ClientAliveCountMax`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ClientAliveCountMax) where the server closes the connection it has sent `n` messages.

This doesn't prevent server messages from ever being sent. For example, if the package was dropped or severe delay caused the message to arrive late, the server will still send a message.

### Filter, ignore the messages

Presumably the messages are sent to `stderr`. Redirect and/or filter `stderr` is probably another viable route.